# Objective c image set size is not distorted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, gpuimage

When i blend 2 image width GPUImage 2 image auto fix same size main image. But main image size horizontal or vertical top image distorted.
I try using image vector, set new size and using nine-patch but new image frame not different.you have answer can help me.

Thank!

[image: Main images]

[image: horizontal and vertical images]

this is my code

```
-(UIImage*)imageBlendFrameDefault:(UIImage *)blenFrame{
    GPUImagePicture *mainPicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:_inputImage];
    GPUImagePicture *topPicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:blenFrame];

    GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];

    [blendFilter setMix:0.8];

    [mainPicture addTarget:blendFilter];
    [topPicture addTarget:blendFilter];


    [mainPicture processImage];
    [topPicture processImage];

    [blendFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];

    UIImage * mergedImage = [blendFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
    return mergedImage;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that you already tried out?

Comment: i add this code. you can help me

Comment: You cannot do what you want to do with those images. Either the "frame" will have to stretch, or the image will have to stretch. You need to re-design your frame so you can take four individual corners, plus "stretchable" or "repeatable" images for the sides.

Comment: thank DonMag Was interested my question. now very late, tomorrow i will try your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cut frame using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions